# How to run all scripts in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to run all opened scripts in SSMS. Would be any shortcut for that? Just like `F5` runs only active one script. The reason I want it is a temporary change in all scripts with `CTRL+H`. I want to run all scripts without saving changes. That is why I do not want the idea of running all scripts in a directory.

**Update.** Nope, manually won't be faster. The reason why I need it is exactly here: [VBA clear just pivot table cache, but leaving pivot table structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32271306/1903793)
I have to run it on 6 scripts not just once, but anytime I make changes to either SQL code or Excel file. Manually is frustrating for that.

Comment: Are you sure of that, beside in which order should they run?

Comment: Your question was asked 3 minutes ago.  You probably could have done it manually by now.

Comment: What exactly are you changing by `Ctrl+H`? Values or code (SQL command clauses)?

Comment: @DanBracuk No, it will not be faster, please see my update of the question.

Comment: Based on the update, there are probably better approaches available.

Comment: @DanBracuk I agree that probably there are better approaches. I just want to learn one or few by asking my question.

Comment: @miroxlav I change `select` to `select top 0`

Comment: Then create one stored procedure for `SELECT` and one for `SELECT TOP 0` and call them from Excel as appropriate (see my answer for more info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this : 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + (<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> ...)

Comment: For reference <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is "Execute current script" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> is "Next tab".

Comment: Ctrl + F6 cycles back to the previous tab (working in the same way as Alt + Tab) so this method doesn't work.

Comment: @anotherdayanotherrob Do not release Ctrl key to avoid step back.

Answer (score 4):

You can kind of do this with SQLCMD mode.

1. Create a new Query.  Make sure Query -- > SQLCMD Mode is enabled.
2. In the new query, enter `:r` followed by the path to the scripts.  So:

`:r C:\Path\To\Script\1.sql`
`:r C:\Path\To\Script\2.sql`
`:r C:\Path\To\Script\3.sql`
`:r C:\Path\To\Script\4.sql`
`:r C:\Path\To\Script\5.sql`
`:r C:\Path\To\Script\6.sql`

3. Run your script.  Each file should be executed in order.

You can't enable SQLCMD mode from within an SQL script, but you can [get it to yell at you or stop executing if it's not enabled](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/can-i-enable-sqlcmd-mode-from-inside-a-script).  You can also set SSMS to always start in SQLCMD mode in Tools --> Options --> Query Execution.

Comment: using double quotes around the path if there's any spaces in it. `:r "C:\Path\To\Script\1 a.sql"`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your drive for improvement. In this case, **create stored procedure which executes all 6 scripts** for you and takes *argument* (which you currently supply by replacing via Ctrl+H).

Then (another improvement) you can update your **VBA code** to connect to the SQL database and **call that stored procedure for you**. This way, you even won't need to open SSMS. Seamless and effective.

See also [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [EXECUTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) and code examples therein.

There is [vast amount of resources on calling stored procedure from Excel](https://www.google.com/search?q=call%20stored%20procedure%20from%20excel).

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way I've found is to open a folder containing your .sql files using SSMS with File > Open Folder ... (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O) which will display them in the Solution Explorer in SSMS.  Double click each file to open and use Ctrl + E to execute. Continue clicking down the list until you are done.

Comment: Yeah...F5 then CTRL+F4...F5 again, then CTRL+F4...
I was hoping there would be a command like "Run All Open Windows".